# Accessing a SSL website from another website

Tags: ssl, https, dns, arduino

I'm pretty new to programming, particularly when it comes to internet stuff, so apologies if this is posted elsewhere already. I have tried and cannot find an answer to it myself here or using google.

Ultimately, I'm trying to make an arduino perform DDNS IP update for me. There ARE several sites explaining how to do this with dyndns.com which is NOT the service I'm using, so they're of no help to me. Additionally, my router is capable of doing this but again only with dyndns.com so again not helping.

I'm using dnsdynamic.org which offers this url for really simple IP updates

https://username:password@www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=techno.ns360.info&myip=127.0.0.1

This works great from a browser, but arduino cannot use SSL. I have looked into this and it appears to be very difficult to get accomplished within the memory constraints of an arduino UNO and even then isn't very effective. Also, I already have code on the arduino other than this which requires the DDNS update.

So my question is, can I create a website that can perform the IP update using the url above that can use SSL and take place OFF of the arduino? (I don't have a computer running 24/7 that can do this for me)

I can retrieve the IP from the arduino and pass it to the website i'm creating. The hope is to then have the website perform the SSL part, update the IP, and pass back a response to the arduino.

That's the only approach I can think of, but i'm completely open to other suggestions.

Comment: [**`cURL`**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) libraries may be of use to you. They can be configured to validate SSL against a locally cached, third-party CA, or the libraries can ignore SSL validation (trusting that no nefarious shenanigans are happening) and proceed with the SSL request.

Comment: Perhaps develop something such as an ASP.NET WebAPI that could be hosted on a free Azure website?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm new to stack overflow so somehow I didn't get notifications of them. I have since found duckdns.org which doesn't require SSL and allows me to update DDNS directly from the Arduino.